# How to restrict the date picker to receive only the numbers and hyphen in the input field and restrict the other values in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vuejs3

I am using vue2-datepicker npm package for date.
Date input takes all alphabets, numbers and special characters
But I want the input to take only the numbers, hyphen and forward slash.
I can do this effortlessly with normal html input. But how to achieve this in date picker.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

[The npm link I am using.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-datepicker)

[Image showing input field taking different values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhWzQ.png)

This is tag and attributes I am using.

```
        <date-picker
          :placeholder="fieldItem.name"
          v-model="fieldItem.value"
          format="MM-DD-YYYY"
          v-if="fieldItem.type == 'datePicker'"
          type="number"
        ></date-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scoped slots to achieve this:

```html
<date-picker
  format='MM-DD-YYYY'
  value-type='format'
  v-model='time'>
  <template #input='{ props, events }'>
    <input
      v-bind='props'
      v-on='events'>
  </template>
</date-picker>
```

> See all slots that `vue2-datepicker` provided [here](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker#slots).

Now we can intercept the input event and remove unwanted characters:

```html
<date-picker
  format='MM-DD-YYYY'
  value-type='format'
  v-model='time'>
  <template #input='{ props, events }'>
  <input
    v-bind='props'
    v-on='{
      ...events,
      input: event => handleInput(event, events.input)
    }'>
  </template>
</date-picker>
```

```js
...
  methods: {
    handleInput (event, update) {
      let value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9/-]/g, '')

      // force Vue to refresh input after remove some characters
      this.$forceUpdate()

      // Apply new value to let vue2-datepicker continue its flow
      update(value)
    }
  }
...
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nfrxd549/)